# Debian 9 boots to black screen

Tags: linux, debian

I’m running Debian 9 with kernel 4.9.0.6 on a Thinkpad T440S. I have Gnome installed but my default DE is i3 .After the last update laptop doesn’t boot to i3 any more. I’m getting a black screen. I’m able to switch tty alt+Ctrl+Fx and log in but after few seconds freezes. I’m again able to select tty and so on. dmesg gives no errors. If I startx I’m able log in to i3 and after few seconds again freeze. Xorg.log error massages are [dix] couldn’t enable device 6 but the number changes all the time.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Recoverymode, then create new user and see if that works.